# Delphi Tokyo 10.2 TDSRestConnection DataSnap Connection on Windows 7

Tags: rest, windows-7, connection, datasnap, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When running a datasnap client application with the componente TDSRestConnection on windows 7 i am encountered the following error:

"Error sending data: (12030) The connection to the server was aborted abnormally."

In windows 10 it runs normally.

In my tests I use windows 7 64 bits service pack 1 with all the updates.

Code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 328
  ClientWidth = 347
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Button1: TButton
    Position.X = 80.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 96.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 161.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 105.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Button1'
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object DSRestConnection1: TDSRestConnection
  Protocol = 'https'
    Host = 'ADRESSS'
    Port = 443
    UrlPath = '/mobisapi.dll'
    UserName = 'LOGIN'
    Password = 'PASSWORD'
    LoginPrompt = False
    ProxyPort = 8080
    Left = 64
    Top = 40
    UniqueId = '{D5182D08-67AE-4227-8583-4DB35F9940FD}'
  end
end

unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  DBXCommon, Datasnap.DSClientRest,
  Datasnap.DSClientMetadata, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DSRestConnection1: TDSRestConnection;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DSRestConnection1.TestConnection;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have the problem because on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are not the default security protocols.

This microsoft pages has the answer and the Easy fix to run and download.

Worked fine for me with my Delphi program.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in